# Django SessionWizardView doesn't execute done method

Tags: python, django, forms, wizard

I can't make my SessionWizardView work. When I submit the last step, the wizard jumps back to the first step and does not execute the done method.

**views.py**

```
class CvWizardView(CookieWizardView):
    form_list = [InfoPersonalForm, PresentacionForm]
    template_name = 'postulantes/cv_wizard.html'

    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('wizard_done'))
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^wizard/$', CvWizardView.as_view() , name="wizard"),
```

**html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block extra_head %}
{{ wizard.form.media }}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<p>Step {{ wizard.steps.step1 }} of {{ wizard.steps.count }}</p>
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
<table>
{{ wizard.management_form }}
{% if wizard.form.forms %}
    {{ wizard.form.management_form }}
    {% for form in wizard.form.forms %}
        {{ form }}
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    {{ wizard.form }}
{% endif %}
</table>
{% if wizard.steps.prev %}
<button name="wizard_goto_step" type="submit" value="{{ wizard.steps.first }}">{% trans "first step" %}</button>
<button name="wizard_goto_step" type="submit" value="{{ wizard.steps.prev }}">{% trans "prev step" %}</button>
{% endif %}
<input type="submit" value="{% trans "submit" %}"/>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Thanks!

Comment: How do you know `done()` method is not called? What is `wizard_done` url?

Answer (score 0):

Try sending the user directly to a html page. In this case change `page_i_want_to_send_user.html` to the name of the page you want the user to be sent to after they complete the form

```
class CvWizardView(CookieWizardView):
    form_list = [InfoPersonalForm, PresentacionForm]
    template_name = 'postulantes/cv_wizard.html'

     def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):  
            return render_to_response('page_i_want_to_send_user.html', {
                'form_data': [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list],            
            })
```

In this case the `page_i_want_to_send_user.html` page is stored inside the templates directory

Comment: Thaks for the answer. I try your solution but it's doesn't work. The form keeps jumping back to the first step after submit in the last step. (sorry for my english)

Answer (score 0):

You may have a field validation error.  Try adding the lines,

```
{{ wizard.form.non_field_errors }}
{{ wizard.form.errors }}
```

after the line,

```
{{ wizard.management_form }}
```

in your html template file.  That should display any validation errors which are preventing the done method from executing.